# PTIJ - Heart transplants

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

[Shemos 25:2](http://mg.alhatorah.org/Full/Shemot/25.1#e0n7) states:

> וְיִקְחוּ־לִ֖י תְּרוּמָ֑ה מֵאֵ֤ת כׇּל־אִישׁ֙ אֲשֶׁ֣ר יִדְּבֶ֣נּוּ לִבּ֔וֹ תִּקְח֖וּ אֶת־תְּרוּמָתִֽי׃
>
> And they should take for me a donation from any man who wishes to donate his heart, they should take his donation.

This is carried out in [Shemos 35:22](http://mg.alhatorah.org/Full/Shemot/35.22#e0n7):

> כל נדיב לב הביאו
>
> Each man who donated his heart brought it

How could the Torah be Matir a heart transplant if Rav Moshe says it is Assur?
(See [this article](http://www.rabbis.org/pdfs/Halachi_%20Issues_the_Determination.pdf).)

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: I have a more practical question: what did they do with all the hearts?

Comment: @msh210 See Devarim 10:16, where they did Milah on the hearts.  Doubtless, Moshe preserved them until them, and they were used when some people needed new ones or extras.  It also explains what the Mohels practiced on.

Comment: But it says there was no _mila_ until the _Charvos Tzurim_ episode in _Y'hoshua_. The heart _mila_ referred to in _D'varim_ is a prophecy about the future, not saying what happened then. So you must be right that the _mohalim_ practiced in the desert. This proves the ancientness of _kabala_: each of these _mohalim_ got _kabala_ from _Moshe_ himself!

Comment: @msh210 B"H we managed to resolve this complicated matter!  Thank you for your Kabbalistic expertise.

Comment: This is a long article, and links go bad or they may be inaccessible from some computers for various reasons. Can you summarize why Rav Moshe says it is assur and include this in your question?

Comment: Rav Moshe says this in a number of Teshuvos in various Chalakim of Yoreh Deah, however, his opinion is debated due to certain individuals claiming he changed his mind, so it's a bit complicated.  Perhaps later.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The passuk in Yechezkel says that HKB"H will take your heart of stone and replace it with a heart of bassar, showing us that when one does tshuva HKB"H does the heart transplant for him, without any maisa biyaddayim on his part, making it muttar. So too, the mishkan was tshuva for the eigal, so it was muttar.

Comment: Excellent! Spoken like a true Uber Chacham!